# Could not setup filebeat on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: logstash, windows-server-2012-r2, elastic-stack, logstash-forwarder

I setup a logserver on a Ubuntu machine. And I need to ship Windows Server 2012 Apache logs to logserver.

Now I am trying to setup filebeat on Windows server to ship logs to logserver: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-getting-started.html

Version : filebeat-1.0.1-windows

But I failed to start filebeat on my server . It threw following error on power shell:

```
Start-Service : Service 'filebeat (filebeat)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service
filebeat on computer '.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Service filebeat
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
   ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

Anyone have the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I  was having this problem with Windows 10.  I ran the following in the command window and found I had a config error in my .yml file:

filebeat -c filebeat.yml -configtest

Once I cleaned that up, the service started.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening an admin cmd  and run the filebeat.exe, you should the errors that would prevent the service from starting.